# Exception handling in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, exception

I'm looking for exception handling mechanism in shell script. Is there any try,catch equivalent mechanism in shell script ?

Comment: Related: [Could someone explain this try/catch alternative in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14964529/320399)

Comment: Related: [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265513/6862601)

Comment: see also [Is there a TRY CATCH command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash). short: use subshells to catch `exit 1`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is not really a `try/catch` in bash (i assume you're using bash), but you can achieve a quite similar behaviour using `&&` or `||`.

In this example, you want to run `fallback_command` if `a_command` **fails** (returns a non-zero value):

```
a_command || fallback_command
```

And in this example, you want to execute `second_command` if `a_command` **is successful** (returns 0):

```
a_command && second_command
```

They can easily be mixed together by using a subshell, for example, the following command will execute `a_command`, if it succeeds it will then run `other_command`, but if `a_command` or `other_command` fails, `fallback_command` will be executed:

```
(a_command && other_command) || fallback_command
```

Comment: Bonus: if you want "finally" like behavior, use the no-op (: in bash) like this: `(a_command || : )` and the next line will run as if no error happened in `a_command`.

Comment: Not really because the semantics of finally is that it runs regardless of the exception state.

Answer (score 13):

The if/else structure and exit codes can help you fake some of it. This should work in Bash or Bourne (sh).

```
if foo ; then
else
  e=$?        # return code from if
  if [ "${e}" -eq "1"]; then
    echo "Foo returned exit code 1"
  elif [ "${e}" -gt "1"]; then
    echo "Foo returned BAD exit code ${e}"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: `if foo ; then
else`
can be simplified to 
`if ! foo ; then`, +1 anyway.

Comment: @jiliagre That does not work. "! foo" inverts $? from 0 to 1 and !0 to 0.

Comment: can this part:
  if [ "${e}" -eq "1"]; then
    echo "Foo returned exit code 1"
  elif [ "${e}" -gt "1"]; then
    echo "Foo returned BAD exit code ${e}"

be simplified to:
  if [ "${e}" -ge "1" ]; then
    echo "Foo returned BAD exit code ${e}"

?

Answer (score 8):

```
{
    # command which may fail and give an error 
} || {
   # command which should be run instead of the above failing      command
}
```

Comment: It would probably be `better` if you explained to the one asking the question, the pseudo-code you post rather than just a block of cryptic code that they may not understand. If a child cannot understand it, it is not a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are [two simple bashfunctions which enable eventhandling](https://gist.github.com/coderofsalvation/8268365) in bash:

You could use it for basic exceptionhandling like this:

```
onFoo(){
  echo "onFoo() called width arg $1!"
}  

foo(){
  [[ -f /tmp/somefile ]] || throw EXCEPTION_FOO_OCCURED "some arg"
} 

addListener EXCEPTION_FOO_OCCURED onFoo
```

Exceptionhandling using try/catch blocks is not supported in bash, however, you might wanna try looking at the BANGSH framework which supports it (its a bit like jquery for bash).

**However**, exceptionhandling without cascading try/catch-blocks is similar to ***eventhandling***, which ***is*** possible in almost **any** language with array-support.

If you want to keep your code nice and tidy (without if/else verbosity), I would recommend to use events.

The suggestion which MatToufoutu recommends (using || and &&) is not recommended for functions, but **ok for simple commands**. (see [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) about the risks)

Answer (score 0):

Use following to handle error properly where error_exit is function that accepts one argument. In case if argument is not passed then it will throw unknown error with LineNo where actually error is happening. Please experiment before actually uses for production -

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

error_exit()

{

    echo "${PROGNAME}: ${1:-"Unknown Error"}" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

echo "Example of error with line number and message"
error_exit "$LINENO: An error has occurred."
```