# My cron job is not working

Tags: shell, cron

I have created one shell script which create backup of mongo and push on bitbucket account.

When I run shell script manually, it works fine. But cronjob does not run

Crontab -

```
00 01,13 * * * /home/ubuntu/work_area/mongodumps/mongo_backup.sh
```

Shell script

```
DIR=`date +%m-%d-%y`
#DEST=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/nitin/mongodumps/$DIR
DEST="/home/ubuntu/work_area/mongodumps"
echo $DEST
#mkdir -p $DEST
mongodump --host localhost --port 17117 -d "db_c2a" -o "$DEST"


git add .
#git commit -m `date +%m%d%y+ autocommit`
git commit -m "Auto commit"+$DIR
git push -u origin master
```

I checked cron log, it is here

```
Jan 28 01:00:01 ip-172-31-26-102 CRON[5506]: (root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/work_area/mongodumps/mongo_backup.sh)
Jan 28 01:00:01 ip-172-31-26-102 CRON[5505]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan 28 01:17:01 ip-172-31-26-102 CRON[5523]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Can you run the shell script as it is without issue?

Comment: @DarthCaniac, yes it runs without issue and pushes the code on bitbucket

Comment: In your script file, can you echo $PATH and $PWD.  It is possible that, when running through cron, these are not what you expect them to be (eg. mongodump and git might not be on that path).  Pipe the output to an absolute pathame (eg "/tmp/something.txt") to ensure you know where it is.

Comment: Try to see if you can follow the guidelines here to manage your cron jobs better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755437/managing-log-files-created-by-cron-jobs/41756145#41756145

Comment: @racraman: I Echoed path, $PWD is correct as expected.

Comment: @user123, great, it means they're correct and that the job IS running.  Next step is capturing what's happening - so stout,stderr.  Cron will try to email these outputs to the job owner, but it looks like you don't have email set up - that's the MTA error (MTA = Mail Transfer Agent).  See eg http://askubuntu.com/questions/7993/how-can-i-setup-a-mail-transfer-agent if you want to, but for now just add "> /tmp/job.log 2>&1" to the command in crontab to capture all the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to see in the log file using command

```bash
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Then there may be some error in running that script.
You can try appending `>> /tmp/mongo_backup.log 2>&1` in your command to see output and error. So you should set

```bash
00 01,13 * * * /some-path/mongo_backup.sh >> /tmp/mylog.log 2>&1
```