# Output not going to file when ran as a cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following bash script:

**clean-tmp.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 tmpreaper 1h /tmp --test > ./tmpreaper.log
```

When I run it in the terminal using `./clean-tmp.sh`, it writes to the file `./tmpreaper.log`.

I added the script to the list of cron jobs using `crontab -e`:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/cron-jobs && ./clean-tmp.sh
```

I then checked cron's logs and this entry is in there every 5 minutes:

```
Feb 19 00:45:01 ip-172-31-23-184 CRON[1475]: (ubuntu) CMD (cd /home/cron-jobs && ./clean-tmp.sh)
```

But it's no longer writing to `./tmpreaper.log`.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the `cd` is succeeding? This is a place where `exec 2>>/tmp/err.log; set -x; cd /home/cron-jobs && ./clean-tmp.sh` would be useful (or even `bash -x ./clean-tmp.sh`).

Comment: Writing to a file using relative path isn't a great programming practice.  In general, it is not good for a script to assume that its current working directory is properly set.  You may want to take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755437/managing-log-files-created-by-cron-jobs

Comment: BTW, the usual cause for this kind of problem is `tmpreaper` not being in cron's PATH. If it's in `/usr/local/bin` for example, that's not there by default.

Comment: What happens when you omit the "> ./tmpreaper.log"? You should get a mail with an error message.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd tend to suggest avoiding `.sh` -- UNIX executables don't generally have extensions; you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, after all; and `.sh` in particular implies that `sh` is an adequate interpreter to run something, whereas `#!/bin/bash` contradicts that by indicating that bash is its intended interpreter).

Comment: @mfnalex, it's only stdout being redirected, so stderr should be getting back to cron regardless.

Comment: You could always try `find / -name tmpreaper.log` : it would tell whether the file ends up somewhere unexpected, or is not created at all, which is not a solution but is at least a clue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffyI actually had 2 problems, but you were absolutely right. My first problem is that I used an alias in the crontab which you shouldn't do: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases. 
As for the second problem, I had to change my script to use `/usr/sbin/tmpreaper` instead of just `tmpreaper`. I figured out where it was by using `which tmpreaper`.  See this link for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47800/command-not-found-when-running-a-script-via-cron 
Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: For the future, I'd suggest using `type` instead of `which` -- while `which` is an external command that looks through the PATH, `type` is built into the shell and can inspect its internal state, finding what a command would do even if it's *not* in a PATH lookup (identifying aliases, functions, etc).

Comment: BTW, your other option is to put an explicit `PATH` line in your crontab -- any variable assignment you put in the header will be exported to the environment. Thus, `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin` or such at the top of your crontab will ensure that contents in `/usr/sbin` can be found for all scripts launched by cron.

Comment: ...as for a proper answer, feel free to write up your own -- or this might be amenable to close-as-duplicate, as we have quite a lot of questions with the same underlying problem (cron's restrictive default PATH).

Answer (score 0):

Just specify an absolute path for your file, like `tmpreaper 1h /tmp --test > /var/log/tmpreaper.log`

Comment: If the `cd` succeeded, then we know the current working directory with certainty. Unless there's another script called `clean-tmp.sh` somewhere else, then `.` can't possibly be anything other than `/home/cron-jobs` when `./clean-tmp.sh` is successfully invoked.

Comment: ...and if it's *not* successfully invoked, then this doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

@Kacy: Little difficult to say without cron logs, you could have a look to cron logs(/var/log/cron etc).

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * cd /home/cron-jobs; ./clean-tmp.sh
```

May be some systems wouldn't allow time period as the way you tried, try once in above way and let us know then.

Comment: If `*/5` weren't valid, then `crontab -e` would have rejected the edit. Also, the question makes it clear that this is logged as invoked every 5 minutes as it is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for your reply, I am not saying it is not valid, I have seen systems where it allows to save it with crontab -e but it doesn't work so only I suggested if user could try once.

Comment: As the OP specified in the question, their syslogs say that cron is actually running the command every 5 minutes.