# Cron job is not triggered on Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

## Ubuntu

In my Ubuntu VM, I have configured a cronjob

**cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/***

```
MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
* * * * * python /home/forge/web-app/database/backup_mysql.py
```

I checked `pgrep cron` I got number printing out fine.

---

It been 5 mins now, I don't see any email send to me. 
I don't see any backup file is being generated.

I have a feeling that this cronjob never got run.

How do I debug this ?

**Do I need to restart some kind of service ?**

Comment: Under which user-id will this job be executed? What does `crontab -l` say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check the cron service.

service cron status.

And check the cronjob logs to check it is running or not

tail -f /var/log/cron | grep `username`

Check the cron
crontab -e -u `username`

And also check permission.

```
chmod +x <file>
```

Comment: I saw it triggered now, but for some reasons the email part is not working.

Comment: I don't see it trigger any email to my email that I set in there. What can I check to debug this further ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755437/managing-log-files-created-by-cron-jobs