# How to get the output of my script saved to a log

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Hello this is purely practicing my cronjob
Here is my bash script below :

```
#!/bin/bash
grep $1 $2
rc=$?

if [ $rc != 0 ]
then
        echo "specified string $1 not present in $2"
else
        echo "specified string $1 is present in the file $2"
fi

# number of lines of in a file
wc -l  $2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Here is my crontab below :

```
20 16 * * * /home/mbarrett/Desktop/ ./find_string.sh sam text_string.file > /var/log/backupstring.log 2>&1
```

Any advice to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `Any advice to what I may be doing wrong?` Depends on what you want to do. I don't see a real question here. Please describe your problem.

Comment: I want to get the output of my script  and put it into a log but my when i open the log there is no output

Comment: Looks fine to me. Does your user under which that crontab is running have access to write to `/var/log/backupstring.log`?

Comment: Yes the user I am under has all the permissions but there is nothing in the log

Comment: I don't no much about `cron`, but that space seems strange. Are you sure you wanted to write `...Desktop/ ./find_string.sh` and not `...Desktop/find_string.sh`?

Comment: I thought  that I need to gave it a path to the script/command that i want to run or is there another way to get the output to log?

Comment: Do you think I should use the pipe command ( | ) in this situation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811738/608639), [Managing log files created by cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41756145/608639), [How to redirect output to a file from within cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52330/56041), etc.

Comment: @malik Yes, you need to give the path to the program you want to run. But the space ends that path, so it's trying to execute the `Desktop` folder as a program.

Comment: @jww That may be what he's asking, but the example crontab entry shows that his problem has nothing to do with the redirection, it's with basic command syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You have the `Desktop` directory at the beginning of your command, which will try to execute it as a program, which won't work. If you want to run the script from that directory, you need to execute the `cd` command to change to it.

```
20 16 * * * cd /home/mbarrett/Desktop/; ./find_string.sh sam text_string.file > /var/log/backupstring.log 2>&1
```

Also, get in the habit of always quoting your variables in the script. Your script as written won't work if the pattern or filename contains whitespace.