# shell script getting called from the crontab but end task in the script is not being performed, but manually it works

Tags: java, python, shell

I have a shell script to send notifications. The shell script works well manually from CLI but when put in crontab it does not perform its end task.

To be more specific I checked the script line by line by sending the outputs to a `cron.log` from crontab which gives the output as expected. But still the end task of sending notification which is via a java command is not working in crontab.

I have checked all possible conditions and don't know what is that i am missing, please help.

crontab:

```
* * * * * bash absolute_path/script.sh > abolutepath/pushNotCron.log
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ condition ]
then
     some code ........
     java -jar $absPath/$jarFileName "argument"
fi
```

No errors in the script

Comment: Try forwarding `stderr` to the file like this:

    * * * * * /bin/bash absolute_path/script.sh &> abolutepath/pushNotCron.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you kick off a job by cron, the shell that gets created by default is created with a minimal environment.  To see this, try running a cron job that simply displays all the environment variables (including the PATH).

Some common ways to address this are :

1) Have all your cron scripts start by running the .profile

2) to explicitly invoke the desired ".profile", so :

`* * * * * bash ./.profile ; absolute_path/script.sh > abolutepath/pushNotCron.log`

3) to have a special cron-wrapper script - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41756145/681444