# Could someone explain this try/catch alternative in bash?

Tags: bash, try-catch

So I found out that bash does not handle exceptions (there is no try/catch).
For my script, I would like to know if a command was successful or not.

This is the part of my code right now:

```
command = "scp -p$port $user:$password@$host:$from $to"
$command 2>/dev/null

if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo 'command was successful'
else
    echo 'damn, there was an error'
fi
```

The things I don't understand are:

- line 3, why do I have to put the `2` behind the `$command`?
- line 5, what exactly is it with this `$`?

Comment: If you intend to do bash scripting, google "sh tutorial" or "bash tutorial", or for more hard-core approacb `man bash`. These are very basic details, and there are more such small details than you can write SO questions about..

Comment: What's the purpose of the `if (( ... )); then ...` ?  Is `cmd; if [ $? == 0 ] ...` fundamentally different?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$?` means the return code of the last executed command.

`2>` means redirecting the `stderr` (standard error stream) output to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 11):

Just FYI, this will also work:

```
if some_command 2>/dev/null ; then
    echo 'command was successful'
else
    echo 'damn, there was an error'
fi
```