# Bash emulation of try/catch not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

The following switch statement has strange behavior:

```
3)
        if [ $state -ne $last_state ]
        then
            echo "state: $state"
        fi

        stty -F $SERIAL $BAUD -echo igncr
        echo "befor cat"
        {
            cat -v $SERIAL >> $USBDRIVE/gpsData_$filecounter.txt && echo "after cat"
        } || {
            echo "catch"
            state=0
            last_state=3
            ((filecounter++))
        }           
        ;;
```

I thought, that when the cat command fails while is beeing excecuted, "after cat" will be written and than the part after || will be excecuted. But when I look at the output, it seems that after echoing "after cat" a break happen so that the actual state does not change and will be entered one more time. Then stty fails, too (becaus the serial adapter is missing). After that, the cat command againt fails at the beginning  but now enters the "catch" block....

Here is the relevant output:

```
pi@rpi ~/serial_logger $ ./serial_logger.sh
serial adapter found: ttyUSB0
state: 1
USB-Storage found: usb0
state: 3
before cat
after cat    #here should be entered state 0
state: 3
stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
before cat
cat: /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
catch
state: 0
USB-Storage found: usb0
state: 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to your current logic, if `after cat` is echoed, that means that `cat` exited successfully.

Comment: but when I comment '&& echo "after cat"' the behaviour remains the same

Comment: As long as the `cat` succeeds (which it appears to be doing), removing the `echo` won't change much (I would expect it to succeed too).

Comment: ok. when the cat command starts while the serial adapter is connected it has succeeded. And when I disconnect the adapter while cat has already started and is running, it has succeeded, too?

Answer (score 2):

### Why it doesn't work

In your example, the `cat` succeeds which is why "after cat" is printed and the "catch group" is not entered.

> I thought, that when the cat command fails while is beeing excecuted, "after cat" will be written

This assumption is wrong, "after cat" will be written only if `cat` succeeds because you used the `&&` operator.

> and than the part after || will be excecuted.

Note that there is no such thing as a "groupfail" which would allow you to actually emulate try/catch behaviour in Bash using command groups (`{ [...] }`). Consider this example with multiple lines inside your group:

```
{
  cmd1
  cmd2
} || { # catch block
```

As long as `cmd2` succeeds, your program will not enter the catch block, even if `cmd1` fails.

### How to emulate try/catch

You could however use the `&&` operator to emulate try/catch behavior:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 || { # catch block
```

This could also be written as

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 ; } || { # catch block
```

You see that however you do it, the syntax is a little clumsy.

Maybe this [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash) can help you too.

### Other error handling mechanisms

Last, but not least, two common Bash error handling mechanisms should be mentioned:

- Registering a signal handler for the `ERR` signal causes Bash to call a function whenever a command returns a non-zero exit status:

  ```
  trap error_handler ERR

  function error_handler() {
    echo error
  }
  ```
- Setting the `errexit` shell option causes your program to terminate as soon as a command returns a non-zero exit status (signal handlers are still executed):

  ```
  set -e
  ```

Comment: ok. But when I use '{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 ; } || { # catch block', the catch block will also only excecuted if cmd1, and only cmd1 fails. Am I right ?

Comment: @Rush: No, the catch block will be entered as soon as one of the commands fails. The remaining commands will not be executed. The catch block will not be entered if all commands succeed.

Comment: Yes I see. But the catch-block will not be executed immediately. This happens only when the cat command has been started correctly. That means that the serial adapter was plugged in. If I run the cat command without plugged serial adapter, the catch-block is executed immediately

Comment: @Rush: I'm not sure I understand :-) If your `cat` succeeds, then the catch block will _not_ be entered. If your `cat` fails, it _will_ be entered immediately.

Comment: Ok, maybe I first try to explain what is my definition of an succeded and unsucceeded execution: The exit-code of an command tells me if an command was successful or not. 0 means successful, 1 unsuccesful. The code is the exit-code of an command, in this case the cat-command. And when we talking about an exit-code, we also talking about an command that has endet, right? That mean that I can not get an exit-code, while the cat-command is still writing stuff from the serial converter in my file.  But: When I disconnect the serial converter, the cat command should give me some exit-code != 0

Comment: and then the catch-block should be executed. But this is not happening. When I disconnect the converter, cat throw an error "cat: /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory" and do NOT enter the catchblock immediately.  When I start the cat-command "cat /dev/ttyUSB0 >> /file" while the serial adapter is not connected, then the catch-block is executed immediately.

Comment: @Rush: OK I see. Your definition of success is the same as mine, but your `cat` seems to succeed when you unplug your converter (it probably just receives an `EOF` from `/dev/ttyUSB0`). I'm not sure how that fits to the message "cat: /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory". However I'm pretty sure that this is not a Bash problem. Have you tried calling `cat` from the command line and then using `echo $?` to check exit status?

Comment: @Rush: Well, there you've got it: Your `cat` returns 0 when you disconnect your adapter. It seems that the usb-serial driver does not consider this an error. There is nothing strange about the shell's behavior in that case.