# Test for failed commands using bash in one-liner

Tags: bash

I would like to output the names of files for which a command succeeds, when I expect it will fail,while suppressing the warnings.  I'd prefer a one-liner.

Something along the lines of:

```
find xml/malformed-xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -exec if xmllint --noout --dtdvalid check-xml.dtd {} 2>/dev/null; then echo "Should have failed for {}"; fi \;
```

or

```
find xml/malformed-xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -i if xmllint --noout --dtdvalid check-xml.dtd {} 2>/dev/null ; then echo "Should have failed for {}"; fi
```

and so far, I am not getting much love.  Suggestions?

Comment: bash has the habit of ditching dear ones ;) provided you don't play it fair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find xml/malformed-xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout --dtdvalid check-xml.dtd  {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

Explanation: in `find`, arguments are implicitly separated by an `-and`. So `-exec ... {} \; -print` is really `-exec ... {} \; -print`. Now because of the short-circuiting logic of `-and`, the second part will only be executed if the first one succeeds.

The reason why both your sugestions fail is that `if ... then ... else ...` is not a program, it's a bash builtin, so you cannot call it from `find -exec` or `xargs`. Both of those programs can execute only actual programs.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might help you:

[Is there a TRY CATCH command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash)

with `||` and `&&` you can substitute a `try-catch` kind of behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling a subshell with "-exec sh -c ... "

```
find xml/malformed-xml -type f -iname '*.xml' -exec sh -c "if xmllint --noout --dtdvalid check-xml.dtd {} 2>/dev/null; then echo Should have failed for {}; fi" \;
```