# How to check if docker daemon is running?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I am trying to create a bash utility script to check if a docker daemon is running in my server.
Is there a better way of checking if the docker daemon is running in my server other than running a code like this?

```
ps -ef | grep docker
root      1250     1  0 13:28 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/dockerd --selinux-enabled
root      1598  1250  0 13:28 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim docker-containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --runtime docker-runc
root     10997 10916  0 19:47 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

I would like to create a bash shell script that will check if my docker daemon is running.  If it is running then do nothing but if it is not then have the docker daemon started.

My pseudocode is something like this.  I am thinking of parsing the output of my ps -ef but I just would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing my pseudocode.

> if(docker is not running)
>
> ```
>           run docker
> ```
>
> end

P.S.
I am no linux expert and I just need to do this utility on my own environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a utility called `pgrep` on almost all the Linux systems.

You can just do:

```
pgrep -f docker > /dev/null || echo "starting docker"
```

Replace the `echo` command with your docker starting command.

Comment: I am aware that the question does not ask for this but on mac pgrep always find a process, as `com.docker.vmne` persists when docker is not running

Comment: To @ScottAnderson's point, if 'Docker Desktop' on MacOS is NOT running, `pgrep -f docker` will return a single value with a low (e.g. 3 digit) pid. When 'Docker Desktop' on MacOS is running, the same command will return a list of higher (5 digit) pid.

So for the MacOS-specific use case, I think `pgrep -f Docker.app` is what you want.

Answer (score 62):

I made a little Script (Mac Osx) to ensure Docker is running by checking the exit code of `docker stats`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Open Docker, only if is not running
if (! docker stats --no-stream ); then
  # On Mac OS this would be the terminal command to launch Docker
  open /Applications/Docker.app
 #Wait until Docker daemon is running and has completed initialisation
while (! docker stats --no-stream ); do
  # Docker takes a few seconds to initialize
  echo "Waiting for Docker to launch..."
  sleep 1
done
fi

#Start the Container..
```

Comment: this is brilliant

Comment: Nice! And we can use `(! docker stats --no-stream &> /dev/null)` to silence the error messages while it's waiting.

Comment: The error wasn't silenced when I did this @Maximilian

Comment: Unfortunately the new Resource Saver mode of docker causes the `docker stats` command to hang in Windows, but only when it's in "saver" mode.

Comment: I can confirm the same is happening under MacOS, i.e. when Resource Saver mode of docker is enabled and active (green leaf symbol on the Docker icon in the top bar), the command docker stats simply hangs

This one works better https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921248/3757063

Answer (score 30):

This works for me on Ubuntu

```
$ systemctl status docker
```

[image]

Comment: This works in Redhat 8 as well

Answer (score 24):

```sh
if curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http/_ping 2>&1 >/dev/null
then
  echo "Running"
else
  echo "Not running"
fi
```

Ref: [Docker api v1.28](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/#operation/SystemPing)

Comment: This should get way more upvotes

Comment: I wonder how to do the same with `wget` ?

Comment: @Enissay `wget` isn't appropriate for this, and that's without saying it isn't a tool shipped by default in Operating Systems like MacOS, while `curl` is available immediately without extra steps.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply:

```sh
docker version > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The exit code of that command will be stored to `$?` so you can check if it's `0`, then docker is running.

`docker version` will `exit 1` if daemon is not running. If other issues are encountered, such as docker not being installed at all, the exit code will vary.

But in the end of the day, if docker is installed and daemon is running, the exit code will be 0.

The `2>&1` will redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and `> /dev/null` will redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` practically silencing the output no matter what was the result of the execution.

Comment: nice! Short and sweet. I like this for fail-fast sanity checking in scripts: if ! docker version > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "Docker isn't running."; exit 1; fi

Answer (score 6):

The following works on macOS and on Windows if git bash is installed. On macOS `open /Applications/Docker.app` would start the docker deamon. Haven't seen anything similar for Windows however.

```
## check docker is running at all
## based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash
{
  ## will throw an error if the docker daemon is not running and jump
  ## to the next code chunk     
  docker ps -q
} || {
  echo "Docker is not running. Please start docker on your computer"
  echo "When docker has finished starting up press [ENTER} to continue"
  read
}
```

Comment: OMG, I found your comment on this gist too! I really like this solution! https://gist.github.com/peterver/ca2d60abc015d334e1054302265b27d9#gistcomment-2642238

Answer (score 5):

You could also just check for the existence of `/var/run/docker.pid`.

Comment: I think this should be `/var/run/docker.sock` for macOS.

Comment: This symlink seems to exist even when docker isn't running :/

Answer (score 4):

Following [@madsonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270958/madsonic), I went for the following

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if (! docker stats --no-stream 2>/dev/null); then
  # On Mac OS this would be the terminal command to launch Docker
  open /Applications/Docker.app
  echo -n "Waiting for Docker to launch"
  sleep 1
  # Wait until Docker daemon is running and has completed initialisation
  while (! docker stats --no-stream >/dev/null 2>&1); do
    # Docker takes a few seconds to initialize
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
  done
fi
echo
echo "Docker started"
```

Answer (score 0):

I launched docker desktop on my Mac, and then ran the command "docker images". It worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the brilliant solution [@madsonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843074/313501) shared

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Wait until Docker is ready
#
# I use a loop, as sometimes the initial "open" command
# fails to launch the app (e.g. when the app is currently
# shutting down). This led to an infitite loop

while (! docker ps &>/dev/null ); do
  open -a Docker; sleep 1
done

# start your containers ...
```

As mentioned in the script comments:

- This script is less likely to end in an infinite loop when the initial `open  -a Docker` command fails
- It's shorter and easier to read

Shortened the code:

- `open -a Docker` is shorter than `open /Applications/Docker.app`
  Note: macOS is smart enough to start the app only once. When Docker
  is already running/starting, macOS will focus on the running instance
  (and not open a new one)
- I found no difference between using `docker ps` and `docker stats --no-stream` in the condition, so I chose the shortest option

Answer (score -1):

A function could looks so:

```
isRunning {
    `ps -ef | grep "[d]ocker" | awk {'print $2'}`
}
```

I created a script to start, stop, restart a mongodb-server.
You only need to change some path inside the scripts, and i also works for you:
[Script](https://github.com/patrick0585/Mongo_Start_Stop)

Comment: `ps -C docker -opid=`

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you want to start the docker daemon so here's the code to start it before executing your Docker run statement:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```