# wait until docker start in Mac OS through shell script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, docker

I am writing a shell script in which I am installing docker on Mac through terminal. I am able to install through `brew cask install docker`. Now it is GUI based docker which wait for user event to continue. Now in my shell script I want hold the execution until docker is started and running. I have found a nice script which checks if docker is running or not. I am able to check it though as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

rep=$(curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://ping > /dev/null)
status=$?

if [ "$status" == "7" ]; then
    echo 'not connected'
    exit 1
fi

echo 'connected'
exit 0
```

I have tried to it put in a loop so that until status is 0 it should check again and again and hold the exception. I have no experience in shell scripting but tried a way to run but failed to do . how can I achieve this.

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

status=0

test() {
rep=$(curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://ping > /dev/null)
status=$?
}

checkDocker() {
while [ "$status" == "7" ]
do
    echo waiting docker to start
    test
done
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843074/133479, here’s the script I came up with while trying to get yours to work. Checking the exit of the `curl` is tricky, because while Docker is starting up, it will respond with an error, but since the response occurs, `curl` considers it OK and `$status` is set to a value other than `7`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while (! docker stats --no-stream ); do
  # Docker takes a few seconds to initialize
  echo "Waiting for Docker to launch..."
  sleep 10
done

docker start $container
```

One thing to consider, however, is that this eventually has output, so you may wish to handle that.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I use. It's a modification of jeffbymes' answer. Instead printing the error messages and waiting for 10 seconds between retries, this just prints a nice message with an ellipsis that grows one dot every second until Docker is ready.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Starting Docker for Mac";

open -a Docker;

while [[ -z "$(! docker stats --no-stream 2> /dev/null)" ]];
  do printf ".";
  sleep 1
done

echo "";
```

Comment: Ooh! Nice improvement 

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with the latest docker update

Comment: This worked just fine for me on an M1 Mac.

Comment: Mine gets stuck at the `printf "Starting Docker for Mac";` until I manually open docker

Comment: Found my issue. Turns out this doesnt work 100% of the time if you have resource saver mode on which is a new experimental feature.