# Unable to run ‘docker-compose build’ on “circleci local execute”

Tags: docker, circleci

This is a docker, docker-compose and django project.

Locally, it works when I run

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test"
```

However, it failed when I run

```
circleci local execute
```

The error I get is

```
docker-compose build

ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
Error:
Exited with code exit status 1
```

Here's the .circleci/config.yml.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8.5
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true
      - run:
          command: |
            docker-compose build
      - run:
          command: |
            docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test"
```

I was using travisci and it just works with the .travis.yml config file below:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.8"

services:
  - docker

before_script: pip install docker-compose

script:
  - docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test"
```

Would appreciate some pointers here. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure docker daemon running in your local machine. `setup_remote_docker` uses your local docker daemon.

Comment: if i run `docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test"` on terminal, it works. but when i run `circleci local execute`, it failed. 

@Subbu any idea on verifying the docker daemon? I'm using Docker Desktop

Comment: It looks like your docker-compose.yml file needs to mount volume `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @MickeyCheong You can check using `docker info` command. Or refer this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978837/how-to-check-if-docker-daemon-is-running

Comment: @mulg0r do you have a link/reference on how to do that? i tried mounting the volume and it didn't work.