# Display messages in tmux before being attached to a session

Tags: tmux

in my tmux.conf I want to incorperate a reminder to install 'tmux plugin manager' if it isn't already installed.

Therefore I came up with this in my tmux.conf:

```
if-shell '[ ! -d "$HOME/.tmux/plugins/tpm" ]' \
    "display-message -p 'TMUX PLUGIN MANAGER is not installed\n Install with: git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm ~/.tmux/plugins/tpm'"
```

When now starting tmux, without the plugin manager installed I get this:

```
/home/user/.tmux.conf:95: no current target
'~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm' returned 127
```

It seems to me the issue here is, that I try to display a notification before I'm attached to a session, which could display the message.

Are there any known workarounds or alternatives for this?

Comment: easy mode would be to alias tmux attach to something that uses `send-keys` and then attaches

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that tmux already has a built in warning that the package manager is not installed (the error you came across):

`/home/user/.tmux.conf:95: no current target
'~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm' returned 127`

So when you run your code, you get that error in your `if` statement. Instead of an `if` statement, try a `||` statement like listed in this SO post: [try-catch in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash)