# How to do try and catch in bash file?

Tags: bash, try-catch

I have shell file (deploy.sh) do the following commands:

```
  npm run build:prod

  docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml build my-app

  docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml push my-app

  aws ecs update-service --cluster ...
```

I want to stop the execution of the bash when error occurred from one of the commands.

Which command does that in shell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error handling in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set -e` to exit on errors. And even better, you can `set -e` and use a trap function.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  set -e
  trap 'catch $? $LINENO' EXIT
  catch() {
   echo "catching!"
   if [ "$1" != "0" ]; then
     # error handling goes here
     echo "Error $1 occurred on $2"
   fi
  }

  npm run build:prod

  docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml build my-app

  docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml push my-app

  aws ecs update-service --cluster ...
```

source: https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/the-bash-trap-trap-ce6083f36700

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test the success or failure of a command, you can rely on its exit code. Knowing that each command will return a `0` on success or any other number on failure, you have a few options on how to handle each command's errors.

## || handler

```sh
npm run build:prod || exit 1
```

## if condition

```sh
if docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml build my-app; then
  printf "success\n"
else
  printf "failure\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

## the $? variable

```sh
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.ecr.yml push my-app
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  printf "Failure\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

## traps

```sh
err_report() {
    echo "Error on line $1"
}
trap 'err_report $LINENO' ERR

aws ecs update-service --cluster ...
```

## set -e

To globally "exit on error", then `set -e` will do just that. It won't give you much info, but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Did a fast search on Google and it seems there isnt. Best is to use `&&` or `||` or `if ... else` blocks see links below:

[SO-Try Catch in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash)
and
[Linuxhint](https://linuxhint.com/bash_error_handling/)

Hope this helps